# Counting points in polygon and extracting the max count of an attribute

Tags: qgis

My first query on here. I'm using QGIS.
I've created a gridded map by counting points in each grid:[image: grid map]

This was generated by counting the number of observation points per grid(polygon).
The attribute table in the observation (polygon) layer looks like this:
[image: attribute table of point layer]
But I now wish to create a similar gridded map, but instead of just counting the number of points within each grid, I wish to count the contribution of each author_id within each grid and add a column which shows the highest contributor within each grid.

Is this doable?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, the answer to nearly every "Is this possible?" question is "Yes", so you'll get a better answer if you actually try to solve the problem, and ask for help if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Instead of using the "Count points in polygon" tool just use the "Join attributes by location" tool.

Found from Vector> Data Management Tools> Join attributes by location

In the option, be sure to set "Attribute summary" to: "Take summary of intersecting features"

If you only want max, you can set "Statistics for summary" to: max

For QGIS 3.14+ this is now done with the Join Attributes by Location (Summary) from:

Processing Toolbox (Accessed from Processing> Toolbox)> Vector general> Join attributes by location (summary)

Comment: At 3.18, I do not see the "Attribute summary" option or the "Statistics for summary" option.  Have they been moved elsewhere?

Comment: I wouldn't use 3.18 right now. It has a lot of bugs.

Comment: Right you are!  I'm now at LTR 3.16.4.  However, I still don't see "Attribute summary" or Statistics for summary".  Can you post a screenshot, along with the QGIS version?

Comment: It can now be done with the Join attributes by location (summary) tool, I updated the answer.